# Symfony's DomCrawler encountered an error with Mink and Behat

Tags: symfony, laravel, behat, mink

This is my first to create BDD in laravel.

This is my feat

```
Feature: GuestBook
   In order to track all of my visitors
   As an admin
   I want to give users the ability to sign in my guestbook

Scenario: With Valid Credentials
   Given I am on "guests/create"
   And I fill in "name" with "John Doe"
   And I press "Submit"
   Then I should see "Guest Book"
   And I should see "John Doe"
```

When I try to run behat

```
  PHP Warning:  DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in /Users/*/Code/bdd2/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.php on line 832
```

This is my stack version

```
php 5.5.*
laravel 4.1.*
```

If anyone encounters and solved the issue already please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug introduced in a recent DomCrawler version. It was already fixed and merged and now all you need to do is wait for a new Symfony release. Until then you can force the previous version of DomCrawler in composer.json.

Related issues:

- https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10986
- https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/10987

Comment: Hey Mate, thanks for the help. I manually update Crawler.php to the fixes they merged. And it works.